# Not quite sure what the point of the %s is in Python, help?

Tags: python, syntax, string-formatting

I'm learning Python from a book right now and I can't figure out what the point is of using the %s to site a specific item in a list, string, dictionary, etc.

For example:

```
names = ["jones", "cohen", "smith", "griffin"]

print(names[1])
print("%s" % names[1])
```

Both commands print "cohen," what's the point of ever using the %s?

Comment: Note "%s" % names[1] is identical to str(names[1]), which is a no-op when names[1] is a str already.  See http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting for all the details.

Answer (score 14):

The idea is to allow you to easily create more complicated output like

```
print("The name is %s!" % names[1])
```

instead of

```
print("The name is " + names[1] + "!")
```

However, as you're just starting to use Python, you should start learning the [new string formatting syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#new-string-formatting) right away:

```
print("The name is {}!".format(names[1])
```

Of course, this example can't show the real power of string formatting methods. You can do much more with those, for example (taken from the docs linked above):

```
>>> '{0}{1}{0}'.format('abra', 'cad')   # arguments' indices can be repeated
'abracadabra'
>>> coord = {'latitude': '37.24N', 'longitude': '-115.81W'}
>>> 'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(**coord)
'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
>>> coord = (3, 5)
>>> 'X: {0[0]};  Y: {0[1]}'.format(coord)
'X: 3;  Y: 5'
>>> # format also supports binary numbers
>>> "int: {0:d};  hex: {0:#x};  oct: {0:#o};  bin: {0:#b}".format(42)
'int: 42;  hex: 0x2a;  oct: 0o52;  bin: 0b101010'
```

and so on...

Comment: Thank you. I'm learning from a book that covers both 2.6 and 3.1 so I believe they're in there

Answer (score 3):

The idea of %s in python is for formating.

```
a = 1.23
print "The value is %0.5f" %(a) # prints 1.23000
```

Answer (score 2):

`%s` is used to construct a string.

In python, like in many other languages, strings are immutable. So, if you concatenate a lot of strings, each of them is created and stored in the memory waiting to be garbage collected.

The point of `%s`, so, is, if you have to join many different strings, construct the string once and hence save unnecessary memory overhead.

It is also arguably a much more convenient syntax than the `+` and breaking strings where need to be.

Answer (score 2):

print(names[1]) just prints the str() representation
print("%s" % names[1]) on the other hand prints the format string "%s" which is filled with names[1]

the effect here is the same.

with print(n1, n2, n3) you can print several data objects separated by a space. think of it as hard coded.

with print(" some format string " % (n1, n2, n3)) you can "beautify" your output. the format string could be a variable that you put together so this could change during runtime of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `%s` is just using what I would call `printf` format.  It's familiar from programming languages like C.  As pointed out by Tim, python has a new preferred way to format strings which you should probably learn.  But the old way is still pretty powerful.  Try `man sprintf` to see how you can specify flags, field width, precision, etc.  I think python's print is compatible with all that.